# Assigning values between events

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing

We have a question concerning the assignment of values between events in Fiware CEP.

Suppose that, based on two triggered events, a third event is initiated. So let’s assume they are called event A, B and C. If A and B are triggered, C should be triggered, assuming that the conditions in EPA are met.

From the log files we can determine that event A and B are being triggered, but event C is triggered but empty. We are so far unable to assign values from event A and B to event C. Our goal is to provide event C with details (a summation of two integers from event A and B) from the events it is triggered by.

Could you provide us with some information into how we can assign values from one event to a new event. Is it possible to use 2 events as input values for a new event? We have tried to assign values to event C by providing them with default values (i.e. by referring to A.variable_1). Also we have tried to assign new event attributes in the EPA -> derivation -> event attributes.

In our Proactive authoring tool we cannot find the solution to our problem. We know the mathematical functions, as described in the user guide, but we failed to deduce how to assign a value from a mathematical function from one event to a new event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate event *C* when event A, B occurred, you can use an EPA of type *All*, and put both *A, B* events as participant events of the EPA.

In this EPA you need to add *C* event as derived event. In the Authoring tool, open the EPA definition, and choose to add *C* as derived event, open its attributes table, and set the attribute you want to be equal to some function based on A,B events (e.g., *A.Value + B.Value*).

See the screen shot taken from the CEP Authoring tool, where the attribute *Value* of the *C* derived event is given the value *A.Value + B.Value*

Make sure you run the CEP with your updated definition file. You need to export it to the repository (from the authoring tool), and then to stop and start the CEP in order to have it run with the updated definition set.

[image: Set the Value attribute of the derived event C]

Comment: When doing the above nothing seems to happen. The output remains empty (we have verified the output of event C by redirecting it to a text file). We reckon it has to do with either the composite context or the EPA.

Our composite context is based on a segmentation context, where we only determine the expression satisfying a certain numerical value.

We see from the log files that events are being triggered to the Proton server.

Regarding the composite context, do event A and B need to be added to it? In any case, we have both added them there.

Comment: Regarding the EPA, what are the exact parameters? We have the following:

tab 1, general: EPA type <all>, with as group event our own <composite context>. 

tab 1, event selection: participant events A and B. Instance selection <first> for both. Both have a condition, i.e. "value > 0".

tab 3, condition: empty.

tab 4, derivation: we have added event C here, containing the parameters of event A and B (like your screen shot). 

To see if works we send the derived event to a consumer which writes it to a text file. When we trigger the events, it does write a new file, however, it is empty.

Comment: As for your first question - yes, A,B events need to be added to the composite context, since they are used in the EPA that uses this context.     As for your issue - maybe you are not running with your updated definitions? you need to export it to the repository (from the authoring tool), and then to stop and start the CEP in order to have it run with the updated definition set

Comment: We are still not able to generate content in the output file. We have remove the output file. When there is a new event, CEP generates a new output file. That seems to work. But there is no content in the file. 
Is there a test case, that produce context in the output file?
The problem is that we cannot see, if CEP open the output file and put content in the file and save’s it. 
Secondly, can CEP run in the bug mode?

Comment: Asking again - are you sure you run the CEP with your updated definition file? you need to export it to the repository (from the authoring tool), and then to stop and start the CEP in order to have it run with the updated definition set.

Comment: If we try to export to our repository from the authoring file, we get a server error. Specifally, 

`java.lang.NullPointerException
 com.ibm.hrl.proton.admin.webapp.resources.DefinitionsResource.getAllDefinitions(DefinitionsResource.java:76)`


(I don't think posting the rest of the error stack is helpful...)
Anyway, NullPointerException seems to suggest that something is missing?

Comment: So the problem is that the export to the CEP failed, and the CEP still run with the old definition set.

Comment: We thought a new question would be more appropriate. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32839582/exporting-cep-definition-file-from-the-authoring-tool-to-an-external-repositor