# Exporting CEP definition file from the authoring tool to an (external) repository

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing

We are having problems with the exporting of the CEP definition file from the authoring tool to an (external) repository.

In the response preview from the developer tools of the browser we get the following error message:

"HTTP Status 500 - A javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader implementation was not found for class org.apache.wink.json4j.JSONArray type and text/html;charset=utf-8 media type. Verify that all entity providers are correctly registered. Add a custom javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader provider to handle the type and media type if a JAX-RS entity provider does not currently exist."

How can we make sure we are able to export to an external repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the external repository is not available.
Since you didn't mention this, my guess is that you are using the default external repository which is http://localhost:8080/ProtonOnWebServerAdmin/resources/definitions
but don't have a running instance of ProtonOnWebServerAdmin. You have got to have ProtonOnWebServerAdmin running on a Tomcat server on your local machine for it to actually process the request.

If you're using anything else - make sure that repository knows how to handle the request.